# Flutter - Dynamically change the carousel items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

This is the kind of structure that I have right now.

[Sample Video](https://vimeo.com/705712366)

As you can see, I have a basic [carousel](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider).
When we click on the blue link button we automatically navigate to the next page. But I also want that page to be removed from the carousel once we click the button.
I tried deleting it from the list but that will simply rebuild the whole screen. I don't want that. Once the user taps on the blue link button user should go to the next page & that card should vanish.

I tried doing some research but did not find any solution where we can remove a carousel item without rebuilding the whole page. Below is my code for this screen. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return Obx(
      () => Container(
        color: kScaffoldColor,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            HomeAppBar(context, () {
              setState(() {
                homeController.filterInit();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              });
            }),
            homeController.isLoading.value ? loader() : myList(homeController.myUsers),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget myList(List<UserModal> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          const Text("No Matches Found"),
          OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                MyStorage().updateUserInDB({
                  um_firebase_token: await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.getIdToken(),
                });
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: const Text("Try Again")),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return myCarousel(list);
    }
  }
```

Carousel Code

```
  Widget myCarousel(List<UserModal> myUsers) {
    return Center(
      child: CarouselSlider.builder(
              itemCount: myUsers.length,
              carouselController: homeController.homeCarouselController,
              options: CarouselOptions(
                onPageChanged: (i, reason) {},
                autoPlay: false,
                height: getPercentageScreenHeight(0.75),
                pageSnapping: true,
                enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                viewportFraction: 0.8,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int realIndex) {
                return PersonCard(
                  myUsers[index],
                  showMenu: true,
                );
              }),
    );
  }
```

Blue Link Button onPressed Code

```
homeController.homeCarouselController.nextPage();
```

Comment: what you are trying to do achievable, please present your code in generic way

Comment: @nitishk72 What I want is that when we click on the blue link button that specific card gets removed from the carousel stack.